# Subset cells based on a changefold level in gene expression

Tags: seurat

is there a way to subset a group of cells based on the foldchange of a gene expression? I have the KRAS object KRAS An object of class Seurat 53805 features across 6826 samples within 1 assay Active assay: RNA (53805 features). I want to subset on the expression of the Olfm4 gene, but with a statistical threshold, for example a logfold2 change of 1. In the meantime I use subset(KRAS,subset='Olfm4'>1).

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us a few more details. What data do you have? In what format? You tagged with seurat, so I guess you are using that tool. If so, please tell us! Ideally, show us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code and data so we can test our answers and make sure we get what you need.

Comment: Could you post how do you have your data which column has this fold change and what what do you expect to achieve? Also it would be helpful to think about the fold change, what are you comparing?

Comment: Hi @IroPierides, Seurat is quite an easy question for this board. If you detail the experiment and/or supply data, I'm sure they'll help. Note very similar questions have been answered in past posts.